# How can I output a list of coordinates for a grouped set of primitives in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Say I have a large set of random points or circles in illustrator.  I select and group them.  How can I output a list of their coordinates (i.e. centerpoints) on the page?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is via the [DrawScript](http://drawscri.pt/) script...

Other than that, you could open the AI file with a text editor and scour the file code for the relative information. I'd stick to the script if it were me though.

Answer (score 1):

You can make Illustrator export as SVG code. If it's just a bunch of primitive shapes like circles, the code won't be very scary and will be pretty readable.

Easiest way...

- File > Save as, choose SVG. Hit save.
- Instead of Okay on the next window, choose 'Show SVG code'

There are loads of resources on SVG out there; though for primitives you can figure out what's what just by looking at it. For example a circle looks like this:

```
<ellipse fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="39.336" cy="36.282" rx="39.336" ry="36.283"/>
```

...where `cx` and `cy` are the x and y co-ordinates of the centre of the ellipse (and `rx` and `ry` are the x and y radius).